# Odoo 14 header customization

Tags: xml, odoo, qweb, odoo-14

In Odoo 14 I would like to edit my invoice. I've been sitting on it for a few hours now and can't get any further. Many header customization are described for Odoo 12 or below and do not give me a concrete answer. I want to have my company address on the right side of the invoice and the buyer's address on the left side where the company address was.

I would like to edit the header so that the company address only appears on the first page and the logo remains on the continuous pages.

When I create a `<div class=header>`. The whole header is no longer displayed on any page.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="web.external_layout_standard">
        <div class="" t-attf-class="header o_company_#{company.id}_layout" t-att-style="report_header_style">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-6 mb4">
                    <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="image_data_uri(company.logo)" style="max-height: 75px;width:80%; object-fit:contain;" alt="Logo"/>
                    <span style="width:150%; font-weight:bold; font-size:smaller;padding:0;margin-bottom:-10px;">Professionelle Businesslösung für Ihren Erfolg</span><br/>
                    <span style="width:150%; font-size:smaller;padding:0;margin-top:-10px;">Smart Solutions - Video Producing - IT Network - Aircraft Solutions</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-9 text-right" style="margin-top:22px;" t-field="company.report_header" name="moto" />
            </div>
            <div t-if="company.logo or company.report_header" class="row zero_min_height">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <div style="border-bottom: 3px solid #fa0219;"/>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row" style="height:15px;">
                <div class="col-6" style="font-size:x-small;width:100%; padding:50px 0 0 50px;height:20px;">
                 <span>test</span>
                </div>
                <div class="col-6" name="company_address" style="float:right; text-align:right;padding-top:15px; ">
                   <div t-field="company.partner_id" t-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}"/>
                      <span class="o_force_ltr" t-field="company.phone"/><br/>
                      <span t-field="company.email"/><br/>
                      <span t-field="company.website"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            

        <div style="" t-attf-class="article o_report_layout_standard o_company_#{company.id}_layout" t-att-data-oe-model="o and o._name" t-att-data-oe-id="o and o.id" t-att-data-oe-lang="o and o.env.context.get('lang')">
            <div style="" class="pt-5">
                <!-- This div ensures that the address is not cropped by the header. -->
                <t style="" t-call="web.address_layout"/>
            </div>
            <div style="" class="pt-5">
              <t t-raw="0"/>
            </div>        
        </div>

        <div t-attf-class="footer o_standard_footer o_company_#{company.id}_layout">
            <div class="" style="border-top: 1px solid #fa0219;color:gray;">

                <div name="financial_infos" style="font-size:smaller; text-align:left;float:left;width:90%;margin-top:5px;">
                    <span t-field="company.report_footer"/>
                    <div t-if="report_type == 'pdf'" class="text-muted">
                      Seite: <span class="page"/> / <span class="topage"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div style="float:right;width:69px; text-align:center;margin-top:5px;font-size:smaller;">
                  <img width="69" height="50" src="data:image/gif;>img</img>
                  <span style="width:100%;margin-bottom:2px;padding:0;">ISO</span>
                  <span style="width:100%;margin-bottom:2px;padding:0;">9001:2015</span>
                  <span style="width:100%;margin-bottom:2px;padding:0;">Zertifiziert</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </t>
```

[image: Report header changes]

Answer (score 1):

Odoo expects `external_layout` to have three main divs: `header`, `article` and `footer` next to each other to render properly.

Looking at your code you put your new lines of code next to a header instead of inside it. This most likely won't work, unless you inherit and change parent view even deeper inside Odoo's source code - which I wouldn't recommend.

You could try putting all of your code inside `header` or `article` divs. See if it at least displays and take it from there.

**EDIT:**

For controlling visibility of a header you could check OCA module [Report Qweb Element Page Visibility](https://github.com/OCA/reporting-engine/tree/13.0/report_qweb_element_page_visibility). Currently there is no version for Odoo 14.0 but it shouldn't be too hard to implement it by yourself as it is basically only a single XML file.

Using functionality from the module above you could just add a class `first-page` to elements that should be only visible on the first page.

```xml
<div class="header">
    <div>
        <!-- Company logo etc - visible on every page -->
    </div>
    <div class="first-page">
        <!-- Company address etc - visible only on the first page -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello, if I rewrite my code so that I have 3 main divs. Will the header and the footer be hidden. I still have no idea what to do about it.

Comment: They will be visible. You could try using OCA module for hiding header - please check my edited answer for details.